# passing parameters to wicket panel

Tags: wicket

firstly wish you all a very happy new year.

i am moving my data tables in to a panel from webpage. i was using pageparameters to pass required parameters on clicking the link for retrieving data and displaying it in the next page. now that i have moved those tables in to a panel i am not sure how to forward those parameters in panels.

My calling Method:

```
final TextField<String> jobnumber = new TextField<String>("jobnumber ", Model.of(""));
        jobnumber .setRequired(true);
        final TextField<String> jobtype= new TextField<String>("jobtype", Model.of(""));
        jobtype.setRequired(true);
        Form form = new Form("form") {

            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                final String jobnumber = jobnumber .getModelObject();

                final String jobtype= jobtype.getModelObject();

                PageParameters params= new PageParameters();
                params.add("jobnumber ", jobnumber );
                params.add("jobtype", jobtype);
                new Job("jobs", params);
            }
        };
        Button button = new Button("button");
        form.add(button);

        form.add(jobnumber);
        form.add(jobtype);
        add(form);
```

My Panel Constructor:

```
public class Job extends Panel {
public Job(String id, **PageParameters params**) {
    super(id);
    String jobnumber = params.get("jobNumber").toString();
    String jobtype= params.get("jobtype").toString();
    add(new Label("jobNumberLabel", jobnumber));
    add(new Label("jobtypeLabel", jobtype));
    list = retrieveJob(jobnumber, jobtype);
    add(new ListView("agilejobs1", list) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            final Job job = (Job) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("jobNumber", job.getJobNumber()));
            item.add(new Label("jobdesc", job.getJobdesc()));
            item.add(new Label("jobcount", job.getJobCount()));

        }
    });
}
}
```

i have tried to replace PageParameters with IModel but it did not work.
Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `IModel<List<Job>>`. You can create one in your panel like this:

```
public class JobPanel extends Panel {
public JobPanel(String id, String jobnumber, String jobtype) {
    super(id);

    IModel<List<Job>> jobListModel = new ListModel<Job>(retrieveJob(jobnumber,jobtype));

    add(new ListView("agilejobs1", jobList) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            final Job job = (Job) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("jobNumber", job.getJobNumber()));
            item.add(new Label("jobdesc", job.getJobdesc()));
            item.add(new Label("jobcount", job.getJobCount()));

        }
    });
}}
```

However, it would be better to construct the `IModel<List<Jobs>>` outside of the Panel and just pass it as an argument. The creation/setting of the model can be done in an Page, an `onSubmit()` in a `Form` or whatever method you like. Then the code becomes much cleaner, as the `JobPanel` will only be responsible for showing the data.